# NotSerializableException: How to know the dependencies that led to an instance being serialized

Tags: java, dependencies, notserializableexception

A NotSerializableException was thrown during java serialization, but the object that is not serializable should not be affected by the serialization process.
How can I know what is the dependency chain that led java to try to serialize that object.

If for example, object D is responsible for the NotSerializableException, so I want to know that:

D is a field of C which is a field of B which is a field of A.

field can obviously also mean "is connected in any way to".

Analyzing the stack trace of the thrown exception I cannot get this information. The project is very complex and the simple stack trace doesn't help me, I can read that RSI is related to an HashSet that is related to a TreeMap, but this is not sufficient to me, I need more specific informations:

`java.io.NotSerializableException: dataprovider.indicator.RSI`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)`
`at java.base/java.util.HashSet.writeObject(HashSet.java:288)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
`at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)`
`at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2434)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)`
`at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)`
`at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1130)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)`
`at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)`
`at ibbridge.Client_v2.serialize(Client_v2.java:1504)`
`at ibbridge.Client_v2.finalizeClient(Client_v2.java:672)`
`at ibbridge.Client_v2.run(Client_v2.java:543)`
`at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)`

Comment: Have a look at the source for `ibbridge.Client_v2.serialize(Client_v2.java:1504)`. What is that serialising?

Comment: @tgdavies Yes Client_v2 is serializable, I just resolved this specific problem, because the situation is not very complex: Client_v2 has a field TreeMap (see the stack trace) that has as Key field a Set implemented as HashSet (see the stack tarce) of interface not mentioned in stack trace, the concrete implementing Class has as field the RSI that throws the exception. This time I get out of trouble, but in more complex situation, the problem may be not so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` JVM parameter. The exception message now should contain the exact 'field' path from the serialized object to the offending class. Also see https://software-creation.nl/2011/07/serializable-exception-in-java/ for more details.